# Count children in parent via CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

How can I count children `<li>` within a `<ul>`?

I want to hide last `<li>` if `<ul>` is have less than or equals to 6 `<li>`'s in one `<ul>`.

**CODE**

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li class="more"><span>Hide this if only 6 li's are there in this ul</span></li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cywkag5j/2/)

Comment: You can't count elements in CSS. You must use javascript to make calculations and then you can add or remove classnames to achieve that you want

Comment: there is a method in css. i know thats lil tricky. but we can achieve it.

Comment: What makes you so sure?

Comment: The question title is very confusing

Comment: @BoltClock : this question can not be marked as duplicate as the one you selected, because solution for both the queries is different.

`li:nth-of-type(5) + li, :nth-child(-n+5).more {
  display: none;
}`

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `nth-of-type()`(or `nth-child()`) plus adjacent selector `+`

```css
li {
  background: red
}
.more {
  background: green
}
li:nth-of-type(5) + li {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<h1> 6 items </h1>

<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li class="more"><span>Hide this if only 6 li's are there in this ul</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<h1> 5 items </h1>


<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li class="more"><span>Hide this if only 6 li's are there in this ul</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<h1> 7 items </h1>

<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li class="more"><span>Hide this if only 6 li's are there in this ul</span>
  </li>
  <li>Seven</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, it's exactly her original question. I put a comment at start instead of this kind of answers because I understand perfectly that she needs to count 6 elements

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude: Her original question says "only 6", and now she's saying "one more condition is... i need to hide it if <li> count is less than or equal to 6."

Comment: CSS is not a programming language. I think that's impossible. You can make weird tricks, but not bulletproof.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to hide the `.more` element *if and only if* (as I've understood from the question) your list has 6 list-items then you could do it in this way

```
li:nth-last-child(6):first-child ~ .more {
  display: none;
}
```

when, counting from the last element, the `nth-last-child(6)` element is also the first child then the list must have exactly 6 list-items.

---

> [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWqjMG)

As you can see from the example, in the first list the 6<sup>th</sup> element is not affected because the list *has not only* 6 list-items

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to achieve this:

```css
li:nth-of-type(6):last-child {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<h3>Remove nothing</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Test #1</li>
  <li>Test #2</li>
  <li>Test #3</li>
  <li>Test #4</li>
  <li>Test #5</li>
  <li>Test #6</li>
  <li>Test #7</li>
</ul>
<h3>Remove #6</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Test #1</li>
  <li>Test #2</li>
  <li>Test #3</li>
  <li>Test #4</li>
  <li>Test #5</li>
  <li>Test #6 (hide this)</li>
</ul>
<h3>Remove nothing</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Test #1</li>
  <li>Test #2</li>
  <li>Test #3</li>
  <li>Test #4</li>
  <li>Test #5</li>
</ul>
```